How to Concatenate Two fields in Title section of Object Page with different formatting and styles?
In my object page I have a title which has a description field. Currently this title is handled via annotation file. I have another field which is string , that also has to be concatenated with the description field in the title section.Each of this field needs to have different styles , also their visibility needs to be handles separately. How can this be achieved ?
I have tried "odata.concat" function, but this cannot have separate styles applied.Can extension points be applied to title section ?
